# HTML More Than One Form With Same Name/ID

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm currently designing a website that reads information from a MySQL database in PHP and prints out a form for each row. This is done using a while loop, so the form is echoed out inside the loop. However, whenever I submit the form, a lot of the values aren't posted because there are forms with the same NAME and ID on the page.

How can I print out one form per item in the database and process this form accordingly? Thanks!

```
while (*this goes through each row in the database) {
    echo "<form name='myForm' id='myForm' method='post' action=''>
          <input type='text' name='text1'>
          </form>";
}
```

I want to use a loop to print out a dynamic number of forms.

Comment: Use a `class` instead, `id` should be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the form name and id with each iteration by adding a counter to your loop.

```
$i = 0;
while (*this goes through each row in the database) {
    echo "<form name='myForm" . $i . "' id='myForm" . $i . "' method='post' action=''>
          <input type='text' name='text1'>
          </form>";
    $i++;
}
```

Or possibly even better is if you have some sort of unique database id for each record, use that id value instead of a counter.

Comment: I like this, but how would I go about processing and validating the form? Would I need to write a function for each form name? Thanks!

Comment: No. You can add a class to the forms and either use jQuery or `document.getElementsByClassName` to grab them all at once.

Comment: @felix_xiao You could use one validation function, just pass the currently submitted form to the function (i.e. using `this`) and act only on the form passed and its child inputs.